# Caching Hibernate entity in a servlet session

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, session, caching

Let's say, I cache the current user in a *servlet session* (or alike) and get a request like "get all books of the current user". Naively, I'd go for

```
hibernateSession
.createCriteria(Book.class)
.add(Restrictions.eq("user", currentUser))
.list();
```

and this works, but in more complicated cases (which I can't reproduce now), I get a

```
TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance
```

So I thought, I should attach the current user to the session somehow. I tried

```
currentUser = (User) session.merge(currentUser);
```

only to find out that it issues a database query, thus making the caching *no better* than storing the id only.

*Can such a caching be done efficiently?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also recommend caching only the ID, rather than the entire entity. However, you are looking for the load(...) method intead of merge(...) or get(...). The advantage of the load(...) method is that it simply generates an entity that is attached to your session without making a query to the database. Assuming that nobody else can come along and delete the record so that you know that your record still exists then the drawbacks to the load method (which are certainly there) are not relevant for your use-case.

[https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#load(java.lang.Class, java.io.Serializable)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#load(java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable))

This will give you an object that you can use to query as in your example

```
hibernateSession
.createCriteria(Book.class)
.add(Restrictions.eq("user", currentUser))
.list();
```

Or else that you can also use to set in other entities while persisting

```
book.setUser(currentUser);
```

In the version of hibernate I tested with, accessing the hashCode(), toString() or equals() method caused the entity to be initialized, including a database query. But provided you only need to use it to query or set your foreign key references while persisting other entities, the load(Class, Serializable) method is what you are looking for.

**Edited - What happens if record does not exist**
You get an ObjectNotFoundException. It extends UnresolvableObjectException which extends HibernateException, which is of course, a RuntimeException. This means that your code exits rather ungracefully (unless you want to catch this exception everywhere - but of course that it is not a reasonable solution)

```
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.yourcode.YourEntity#id that does not exist]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl$2.handleEntityNotFound(SessionFactoryImpl.java:419)
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.checkTargetState(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:154)
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:143)
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:174)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
at com.yourcode.YourEntity_$$_javassist_143.getNonIdentifierMethod(YourEntity_$$_javassist_143.java)
at com.yourcode.YourBusinessLogic.method(YourBusinessLogic.java:56)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I guess, this is what I was after. Could you add some information about what disaster happens when using `load` with a deleted entity? That's not a part of my question, but something I've never seem to understand from the Hibernate documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Why not cache the id only?  For the Books query, you could simply do this:

```
hibernateSession
.createCriteria(Book.class)
.add(Restrictions.eq("user.id", currentUserId))
.list();
```

If you need the cached user object for other reasons, you could simply use `currentUser.id`, rather than `currentUserId`.

Comment: Sure, but for `Book` creation I need the `user` itself. Maybe I could use some cascading merge... (as for now, I'm avoiding cascade as I prefer to be explicit about that).

Comment: The merging (or loading) approach still offers a performance advantage, in that you only need to access the persistent entity for some operations.  I'll guess that in your application, reviewing the Books list will be done more often than creating new books.